# Is there a way to include BCC recipients in an InfoView publication?

Tags: business-intelligence, business-objects, infoview

I am setting up a publication in InfoView that will use bursting to email Business Objects reports (in Web Intelligence format) to the selected recipients. When changing the properties of a publication, I'm able to set a **"To" field** and a **CC field**, but a **BCC field does not show up.** Is there a way to do this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

As you mentioned InfoView, I suspect you're still running XI3 or an earlier version of BusinessObjects.

As mentioned in SAP note [1369269](https://service.sap.com/sap/support/notes/1369269), there is no support for BCC when scheduling/publishing to e-mail.

SAP note [1626654](https://service.sap.com/sap/support/notes/1626654) starting from SAP BusinessObjects BI Platform 4.0 Feature Pack 3 (FP3).

I've taken screenshots from the scheduling and publishing properties in BI 4.1 SP4 where you can see the BCC field is available.

**Scheduling**

[image: Scheduling options]

**Publishing**

[image: Publication options]

Comment: I didn't even consider that. We are running XI3. Thanks for your help!